# Select columns from LazyFrame by condition

Tags: python-polars

`polars.LazyFrame.var` will return variance value for each column in a table as below:

```
>>> df = pl.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3, 4], "b": [1, 2, 1, 1], "c": [1, 1, 1, 1]}).lazy()
>>> df.collect()
shape: (4, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 1   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
>>> df.var().collect()
shape: (1, 3)
┌──────────┬──────┬─────┐
│ a        ┆ b    ┆ c   │
│ ---      ┆ ---  ┆ --- │
│ f64      ┆ f64  ┆ f64 │
╞══════════╪══════╪═════╡
│ 1.666667 ┆ 0.25 ┆ 0.0 │
└──────────┴──────┴─────┘
```

I wish to select columns with value > 0 from LazyFrame but couldn't find the solution.

I can iterate over columns in polars dataframe then filter columns by condition as below:

```
>>> data.var()
shape: (1, 3)
┌──────────┬──────┬─────┐
│ a        ┆ b    ┆ c   │
│ ---      ┆ ---  ┆ --- │
│ f64      ┆ f64  ┆ f64 │
╞══════════╪══════╪═════╡
│ 1.666667 ┆ 0.25 ┆ 0.0 │
└──────────┴──────┴─────┘
>>> cols = pl.select([s for s in data.var() if (s > 0).all()]).columns
>>> cols
['a', 'b']
>>> data.select(cols)
shape: (4, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 2   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 1   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ 1   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

But it doesn't work in LazyFrame:

```
>>> data = data.lazy()
>>> data
<polars.internals.lazyframe.frame.LazyFrame object at 0x7f0e3d9966a0>
>>> cols = pl.select([s for s in data.var() if (s > 0).all()]).columns
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
  File "/home/jasmine/miniconda3/envs/jupyternb/lib/python3.9/site-packages/polars/internals/lazyframe/frame.py", line 421, in __getitem__
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: 'LazyFrame' object is not subscriptable (aside from slicing). Use 'select()' or 'filter()' instead.
```

The reason for doing this in LazyFrame is that we want to maximize the performance. Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

polars doesn't know what the variance is until after it is calculated but that's the same time that it is displaying the results so there's no way to filter the columns reported and also have it be more performant than just displaying all the columns, at least with respect to the polars calculation.  It could be that python/jupyter takes longer to display more results than fewer.

With that said you could do something like this:

```
df.var().melt().filter(pl.col('value')>0).collect()
```

which gives you what you want in one line but it's a different shape.

You could also do something like this:

```
dfvar=df.var()
dfvar.select(dfvar.melt().filter(pl.col('value')>0).select('variable').collect().to_series().to_list()).collect()
```

Comment: This looks much more performant than what I did, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer from @dean MacGregor, we:

- do the var calculation
- melt
- apply the filter
- extract the `variable` column with column names
- pass it as a list to `select`

````py
df.select(
     (
         df.var().melt().filter(pl.col('value')>0).collect()
         ["variable"]
      )
    .to_list()
    ).collect()
shape: (4, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 2   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 1   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ 1   │
└─────┴─────┘
```
````