# Select columns in a Polars LazyFrame based on a condition without collect?

Tags: lazy-evaluation, python-polars

We often want to remove columns from a LazyFrame that don't fit a condition or threshold evaluated over that column (variance, number of missing values, number of unique values). It's possible to evaluate a condition over a LazyFrame columnwise, collect that condition, and pass it as a list to the same LazyFrame (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74428888/select-columns-from-lazyframe-by-condition)). Is it possible to do this without evaluating an intermediate result?

A toy example would be to select only the columns that have 10 or more unique values. I can do this following the example from the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74428888/select-columns-from-lazyframe-by-condition):

```py
threshold = 10
df = ldf.select(
    ldf.select(pl.all().n_unique())
    .melt()
    .filter(pl.col("value") >= threshold)
    .select("variable")
    .collect() # this evaluates the condition over the dataframe
    .to_series()
    .to_list()
).collect()
```

I would like to do this with only one `collect()` statement at the end.

Comment: Perhaps a silly suggestion - if you wanted to ignore them - could you null out the columns e.g. `ldf.with_columns(pl.when(pl.all().n_unique() >= threshold).then(pl.all()).keep_name())` then remove the null columns after you `.collect()`?

Comment: Thanks! This will be helpful in reducing the memory of the array loaded into memory, but is there a better way to remove the null columns? I've tried casting only those columns to a categorical type or renaming those columns to something that we can select using a regex but I'm not able to isolate just the columns which match the condition.

Comment: You mean how to drop the null columns after the collect? See the last [`.drop_nulls()` example](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.drop_nulls.html#polars.DataFrame.drop_nulls)

Comment: What first came to my mind was `.drop()` e.g. `df.drop([col.name for col in df if col.is_null().all()])` - I'm not sure if there is any performance difference versus the example from the docs.

Comment: Sorry, I meant prior to the `collect` call. I'm doing this for multiple large files and it'd be nice to gather everything into a `collect_all` call at the end as opposed to looping over the files after a `collect_all`.

Comment: My understanding from what I've read is that it would have to be done afterwards. I've not really used LazyFrames though, so I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is impossible without a collect. With `LazyFrames` you are making a computation graph. Every node in that graph has a known schema that is defined before running the query.

It is impossible to know what the schema is if the columns you select are dependent on the "running" the query.

In short, you have to `collect` and then continue lazy from that point.