# Polars and the Lazy API: How to drop columns that contain only null values?

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I am working with **Polars** and need to drop columns that contain only null values during my data preprocessing. However, I am having trouble using the **Lazy API** to accomplish this.

For instance, given the table below, how can I drop column "a" using Polars' Lazy API?

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [None, None, None, None],
        "b": [1, 2, None, 1],
        "c": [1, None, None, 1],
    }
)
df
```

```
shape: (4, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ a    ┆ b    ┆ c    │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ f64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ null ┆ 1    ┆ 1    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ null ┆ 2    ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ null ┆ null ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ null ┆ 1    ┆ 1    │
└──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

I am aware of [Issue #1613](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/1613) and the solution of filtering columns where all values are null, but this is not Lazy API.

FYI,

```
# filter columns where all values are null
df[:, [not (s.null_count() == df.height) for s in df]]
```

I am also aware of the [drop_nulls](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.drop_nulls.html) function in Polars, which can only drop all rows that contain null values, unlike the [dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) function in Pandas that can take two arguments, `axis` and `how`.
Can someone provide an example of how to drop columns with all null values in Polars using the Lazy API?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but you could try `pl.LazyFrame(s for s in df if s.is_not_null().any()).collect()`. Or using the logic from the question: `pl.LazyFrame(s for s in df if s.null_count() != df.height).collect()`.

Comment: Might be useful for added info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75233763

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, at least not in the way you want. polars doesn't know enough about the lazyframe to tell which columns are only nulls until you `collect`. That means you need a collect in order to get the columns you want and then another one to materialize the columns you wanted.

Let's turn your `df=df.lazy()`

Step 1:

```
(df.select(pl.all().is_null().all())
    .melt()
    .filter(pl.col('value')==False)
    .select('variable')
    .collect()
    .to_series()
    .to_list())
```

Those are your columns that have no nulls so now you wrap it in its own select

Step 2:

```
(df.select(
    df.select(pl.all().is_null().all())
        .melt()
        .filter(pl.col('value')==False)
        .select('variable')
        .collect()
        .to_series()
        .to_list())
.collect())
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [drop](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.drop.html#) and [selectors](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/selectors.html#) [by type](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/selectors.html#polars.selectors.by_dtype):

```
import polars as pl
import datetime

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "integer": [1, 1, 2, 3],
        "date": [
            None,
            datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1),
            datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 2),
            datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 3),
        ],
        "float": [4.0, 3.0, 5.0, None],
        "string": [None, None, None, None],
    },
).lazy()
print(df.drop(pl.selectors.by_dtype(pl.Null)).fetch())
```

Answer (score 1):

This example uses Rust Polars version = "0.36.2".

According to the solution presented by [Timus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14311263/timus) and adapted for Rust polars:

In this example, I want to remove all columns that contain only null values, with the exception of the `options B` column.

Cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies.polars]
version = "0.36.2"
features = [
    "lazy",  # Lazy API
]
```

main.rs:

```
use polars::prelude::*;
use std::error::Error;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let dataframe: DataFrame = df!(
        "integers"  => &[1, 2, 3, 4],
        "options A" => [None::<u32>, None, None, None],
        "float64"   => [23.654, 0.319, 10.0049, -3.41501],
        "options B" => [None::<u32>, None, None, None],
        "options C" => [Some(28), Some(300), None, Some(2)],
        "options D" => [None::<u32>, None, None, None],
    )?;

    println!("dataframe: {dataframe}\n");

    let df_clean: DataFrame = remove_null_columns(Frame::Data(dataframe))?;

    println!("df_clean: {df_clean}\n");

    assert_eq!(
        df_clean,
        df!(
            "integers"  => &[1, 2, 3, 4],
            "float64"   => [23.654, 0.319, 10.0049, -3.41501],
            "options B" => [None::<u32>, None, None, None],
            "options C" => [Some(28), Some(300), None, Some(2)],
        )?
    );

    Ok(())
}
```

With `remove_null_columns()` given by:

```
pub enum Frame {
    Lazy(LazyFrame),
    Data(DataFrame),
}
 
 /// Eliminate columns that contain only null values.
 /// 
 /// frame can be LazyFrame or DataFrame
 ///
 /// <https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/1613>
 pub fn remove_null_columns(frame: Frame) -> PolarsResult<DataFrame> {
 
    let df: DataFrame = match frame {
        Frame::Lazy(lz) => lz.collect()?,
        Frame::Data(df) => df,
    };

    let maintain = "options B";

    let df_clean: DataFrame = df
        .iter()
        //.filter(|series| series.is_not_null().any())
        .filter(|series| series.is_not_null().any() || series.name().contains(maintain))
        .cloned()
        .collect();

    Ok(df_clean)
}
```

The output:

```
dataframe: shape: (4, 6)
┌──────────┬───────────┬──────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ integers ┆ options A ┆ float64  ┆ options B ┆ options C ┆ options D │
│ ---      ┆ ---       ┆ ---      ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ i32      ┆ u32       ┆ f64      ┆ u32       ┆ i32       ┆ u32       │
╞══════════╪═══════════╪══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 1        ┆ null      ┆ 23.654   ┆ null      ┆ 28        ┆ null      │
│ 2        ┆ null      ┆ 0.319    ┆ null      ┆ 300       ┆ null      │
│ 3        ┆ null      ┆ 10.0049  ┆ null      ┆ null      ┆ null      │
│ 4        ┆ null      ┆ -3.41501 ┆ null      ┆ 2         ┆ null      │
└──────────┴───────────┴──────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘

df_clean: shape: (4, 4)
┌──────────┬──────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ integers ┆ float64  ┆ options B ┆ options C │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ i32      ┆ f64      ┆ u32       ┆ i32       │
╞══════════╪══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 1        ┆ 23.654   ┆ null      ┆ 28        │
│ 2        ┆ 0.319    ┆ null      ┆ 300       │
│ 3        ┆ 10.0049  ┆ null      ┆ null      │
│ 4        ┆ -3.41501 ┆ null      ┆ 2         │
└──────────┴──────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```